# Dotted Stroke overlapping

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to apply a dash line stroke around shapes. But the dash/dots are not spaced equally. Two dots are overlapping at a certain point (in a circle). For rectangle shape, they are not evenly spaced.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use Photoshop for work like this. Much better to use Illuatrator. [A Pattern Brush](https://imgur.com/2RcOj9q) with "Add space to fit" would easily work for the dots around a circle of any size. I can add an answer for Illustrator if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew the illustrator one. wanted to learn if photoshop has any solution. stay safe Billy.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible in Photoshop, but it would likely require lots more work. Photoshop doesn't have the vector editing capabilities that Illustrator has. It's very basic by comparison. It's just so much easier in Illustrator.

Comment: Yes, before posting here I always try to research first. found no solution, You people here are like master oogway, All of you know so much, so I always know this place won't fail me. After your comment, I drew that figure in the illustrator and placed that in photoshop. donot know why i didn't think that in the first place.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer for Illustrator now. Might be useful if others don't know the technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better to use Illustrator for work like this because it's easier.

In Illustrator you can define a Pattern Brush using the "Add space to fit" option.

This will work on circles or rectangles.

Example

[image]

And of course, it's possible to place an AI file in Photoshop too.

Comment: Proper tool for the task. Easiest workaround...